# how to add padding to a UILabel who's text includes a NSBackgroundColorAttributeName

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I'm having trouble trying to figure out a way to add padding to my UILabel which includes an attributed string that contains a background color for text.

[image]

as shown in the image, there isn't any left padding on the label's text - i need to be able to add some padding to the left and the right.
here is my current code:

```
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(blueHighlightedText)")
attributedString.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor(red: 0.369, green: 0.718, blue: 0.882, alpha: 0.83), range: NSMakeRange(0, blueHighlightedText.bridgeToObjectiveC().length))
attributedString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, blueHighlightedText.bridgeToObjectiveC().length))
attributedString.addAttribute(NSKernAttributeName, value: -0.35, range: NSMakeRange(0, blueHighlightedText.bridgeToObjectiveC().length))

attributedText = NSAttributedString(attributedString: attributedString)
```

How can i add padding to this?

Comment: Did you try to add some space after you string ? This should fix your right padding, and for the left just add a subview with a color background at the left of your label

Comment: The only issue I see with this option is that there will be times that my label will contain multiple lines

Answer (score 0):

Set the contentEdgeInsets of the label, or add the label as a subview to a colored view and position.

Comment: the edge insets would not work as the NSBackgroundColorAttributeName draws the background color where text is displayed, which is also why adding the label as a subview to a colored view and position would not work either.